# How to split a text file using tab space in c?

Tags: c, split

I am doing a socket programming for that I having the following details in the text file. I want to split that text file using tab space and I need to assign them to the variables how can I achieve that?

Here is my text file

```
001 Coffee maker    10  3000.00
002 Pressure cooker 4   7000.00
003 Blender 10  2500.00
004 Pillow  10  300.00
005 Camera  5   25000.00
006 Washer  5   25000.00
007 Headphone   3   5000.00
008 Mattresses  5   6000.00
009 Heater  3   1000.00
010 Cookware    2   10000.00
```

Comment: Use `sscanf` or `strtok` or both

Comment: by using sscanf

Comment: If you've gotten far enough to find `sscanf`, do you also have some code that you've tried already?

Comment: sscanf(line,"%d\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%d",&no,&q,&ma,&a); this is the one i tried

Comment: `sscanf` doesn't do regex. You can only do `%d`, `%s`, `%f`... (with optionally digit length etc. between the `%` and `d`/`s`/`f`...), just like in `printf`

Comment: so can u please give me a solution for it?

Comment: Er, oops. You can use stuff like `[^\t]` in fact. Sorry. Sec, going to check if this can be done using a single `sscanf` call

Comment: I can't get it to work for the following two cases at the same time: 1) input where e.g. "Coffee maker" fits into the buffer (normal) and 2) where that part of the input doesn't fit into the buffer (would probably want it to cut it off without breaking the following formats).
`"%d\t%63[^\t]\t%d\t%f"`: For overflows of `%63[^\t]`, `%d` and `%f` turn into junk.

Comment: I usually avoid processing strings in C, but if I'd have to do this one, I'd probably use `strtok` to get rid of the delimiters, and then use `strtof`/`atoi` (or even `sscanf`) for the numbers

Comment: @visva you shouldn't post three times the same question

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sample code to read line-by-line from file and split strings at tab character.

strtok modifies the source string passed and it uses static buffer while parsing, so it's not thread safe. If no delimiter is present in the line then the first call to strtok returns the whole string. You need to handle this case.

```
void split_string(char *line) {
    const char delimiter[] = "\t";
    char *tmp;

    tmp = strtok(line, delimiter);
    if (tmp == NULL)
    return;

    printf("%s\n", tmp);

    for (;;) {
        tmp = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        if (tmp == NULL)
            break;
        printf("%s\n", tmp);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t size;
    FILE *fp = fopen("split_text.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    while (getline(&line, &size, fp) != -1) {
        split_string(line);
    }

    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid `strtok()` is not the perfect tool for this: it cannot handle empty fields: a sequence of tabs will be considered a single separator.

Answer (score 1):

Your problems is one of the rare instance where reading *formatted input* with the *formatted input* function `scanf` (or reading a line and using `sscanf`) actually makes sense. If your records are `tab` separated values, then you can craft a `scanf` *format string* to read each of your fields in a reasonably clean manner.

The key for using `scanf` is to always validate the **return** (the number of successful conversions that took place based on the number of *format specifiers* in your *format string*). You must also protect array widths if you are reading strings into fixed buffers to prevent writing beyond array or allocation bounds by using the appropriate *field-width* modifiers.

Putting those pieces together, you could do something like the following:

```
    int rtn = scanf (" %7s\t%63[^\t]\t%u\t%lf",  /* save scanf return */
                        tmp.idx, tmp.desc, &tmp.n, &tmp.price);
```

(with your storage sized appropriately -- I guessed at what your fields were)

Speaking of storage, any time you have data of different `types` that you need to coordinate, you should think `struct`. Here, for example purposes, a `struct` with  reasonably sized fixed buffers is fine, e.g.

```
/* constants - index, description width, max records */
enum { IDX = 8, DESC = 64, MAXR = 128 };

typedef struct {    /* struct to hold each record values */
    char idx[IDX],  /* 1st field */
        desc[DESC]; /* 2nd field */
    double price;   /* 4th & 3rd - ordered to put smallest last */
    unsigned n;
} rec_t;
```

To handle your storage needs, you simply declare an array of `rec_t`, e.g.

```
    rec_t record[MAXR] = {{ .idx = "" }},   /* array of struct */
        tmp = { .idx = "" };                /* tmp struct for read */
```

When reading into an array of struct, it is often useful to use a temporary struct to fill with values from `scanf` (or whatever you are using), and then after validating your `scanf` return (conversions), you can simply assign the `tmp` struct to the next element in your array and increment the array index, e.g.

```
        if (rtn == 4)           /* validate 4 conversions */
            record[n++] = tmp;  /* assign tmp to record[n], increment */
```

I find it easier to simply loop continually when taking input with `scanf` and then validate the return, checking for `EOF` and then simply break your read-loop if you encounter `EOF` (or you otherwise satisfy your input needs).

Putting all the pieces together, you could do something like the following, which happily skips the empty lines in your file shown above, only storing values when the `scanf` return indicates all successful conversions took place. The program reads data on `stdin`, though you can easily modify the code to open a given filename for the read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* constants - index, description width, max records */
enum { IDX = 8, DESC = 64, MAXR = 128 };

typedef struct {    /* struct to hold each record values */
    char idx[IDX],  /* 1st field */
        desc[DESC]; /* 2nd field */
    double price;   /* 4th & 3rd - ordered to put smallest last */
    unsigned n;
} rec_t;

int main (void) {

    rec_t record[MAXR] = {{ .idx = "" }},   /* array of struct */
        tmp = { .idx = "" };                /* tmp struct for read */
    unsigned n = 0;                         /* n - records */

    while (n < MAXR) {  /* loop while n < max records (MAXR) */
        int rtn = scanf (" %7s\t%63[^\t]\t%u\t%lf",  /* save scanf return */
                        tmp.idx, tmp.desc, &tmp.n, &tmp.price);
        if (rtn == EOF)         /* return EOF? */
            break;
        if (rtn == 4)           /* validate 4 conversions */
            record[n++] = tmp;  /* assign tmp to record[n], increment */
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++)    /* output array */
        printf ("record[%3u]:  %-8s %-24s %3u    %9.2f\n", i, record[i].idx, 
                record[i].desc, record[i].n, record[i].price);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readtsv <dat/file.tsv
record[  0]:  001      Coffee maker              10      3000.00
record[  1]:  002      Pressure cooker            4      7000.00
record[  2]:  003      Blender                   10      2500.00
record[  3]:  004      Pillow                    10       300.00
record[  4]:  005      Camera                     5     25000.00
record[  5]:  006      Washer                     5     25000.00
record[  6]:  007      Headphone                  3      5000.00
record[  7]:  008      Mattresses                 5      6000.00
record[  8]:  009      Heater                     3      1000.00
record[  9]:  010      Cookware                   2     10000.00
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I'm afraid `scanf()` is not the perfect tool for this: it cannot handle empty fields. `%[^\t]` requires at least one character different from `'\t'` to succeed.

Comment: Nope, nobody said it was perfect. Even `strtok` fails for empty fields (where `strsep` would be the tool of choice -- or walking a pointer down the buffer). Thanks for making that clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simplistic parser with `sscanf()` or `strtok()` but be aware that neither of these will handle empty fields correctly. `scanf`'s `%[^\t]` conversion specifier will fail if there are no characters before the next tab, and `strtok()` will consider any sequence of tabs a single delimiter.

Here is a solution with an ad hoc utility function that behaves similarly to `strtok()` but without its shortcomings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getfield(char **pp, char sep) {
    char *p, *res;
    for (res = p = *pp;; p++) {
        if (*p == sep) {
            *p++ = '\0';
            *pp = p;
            return res;
        }
        if (*p == '\0')
            return NULL;
    }
}

int main() {
    char line[256];
    char filename[] = "input_file.txt";
    int lineno = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
            char *p = line;
            char *reference = getfield(&p, '\t');
            char *description = getfield(&p, '\t');
            char *quantity = getfield(&p, '\t');
            char *price = strtod(getfield(&p, '\n');
            lineno++;
            if (price != NULL) {
                /* all fields were parsed correctly */
                printf("reference: %s\n, reference);
                printf("description: %s\n, description);
                printf("quantity: %d\n, atoi(quantity));
                printf("price: %.2f\n\n, strtod(price, NULL));
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: invalid line\n", filename, lineno);
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```